# what is the difference between jquery selectors and js selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question for a noob. Is there a difference between these to variables?

```
var object1 = document.getElementById('myElement');
var object2 = $('#myElement');
```

Also, am I able to run normal js stuff on object2? For example, if #myElement is a `<textarea>` can I do:

```
object2.value = "fill in with this text";
```

or, must I do:

```
$(object2).val('fill in with this text');
```

or, is there yet a better way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var object1 = document.getElementById('myElement');
```

You get a DOM element object from this call. Thus, you use the `value` property to give it a value.

```
object1.value = "text";
```

---

```
var object2 = $('#myElement');
```

You get a jQuery object from this call. Inside the jQuery object is a DOM object. Think of the jQuery object as a **wrapper** for the DOM object. Diagrammatically it looks something like this (simplified):

```
jQuery ------------------+
|                        |
| Array ---------------+ |
| |                    | |
| | HTMLElement------+ | |
| | |                | | |
| | | DOM properties | | |
| | | DOM element    | | |
| | |     methods    | | |
| | |                | | |
| | +----------------+ | |
| | there may be zero, | |
| | one or more such   | |
| | objects inside     | |
| +--------------------+ |
| jQuery properties      |
| jQuery methods         |
|                        |
+------------------------+
```

Since `object2` is a jQuery object, you use the `val()` function to give it a value. You cannot use the `value` property because it's not the same as a DOM object.

```
object2.val("text");
```

Like the other answers say, you *can* access the underlying DOM object using array dereferencing (`object2[0]`) or the `get()` function, then giving it a value using `value`.

Comment: To add further, explicit clarification, you cannot use vanilla js methods on a jQuery object, as they are a set of elements (even if it only yields on element).

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as "inside" the jQuery object, it just has a *reference to* the element in question, there's no "container" like behavior going on :)

Comment: @NickCraver ~ Till you detach it, no? Where does it go once detached?

Answer (score 3):

The first is a DOM element, the second is a jQuery object with a reference to the same DOM element.

This won't work: `object2.value = "fill in with this text";` since the jQuery object doesn't have a `.value` property, but this will:

```
object1.value = "fill in with this text";
```

To get the raw DOM element from `$('#myElement')`, use `[0]` or `.get(0)` like this:

```
$('#myElement')[0].value = "fill in with this text";
```

Answer (score 1):

object2 is now a jQuery object, so cannot be treated as a standard element. You could, however, get it by referencing `object2[0]` which gives you the first element in the jQuery object.

So you could either use `object2[0].value = "fill in with this text";` or you could just use the jquery `.val()` way. But also note that you don't need to do

```
$(object2).val('fill in with this text');
```

as this would also suffice:

```
object2.val('fill in with this text');
```

since object2 is already a jQuery object.

---

Lastly a note: `jQuery(object1)` (where object1 is *already* a DOM element) would give you a jQuery object the same as had you `$('myElement')` but the jQuery selector may in some cases be faster or optimized over the document selector that is native to the browser. It won't always be faster, but in some cases it may be.

`.getElementById` (as noted below) should be equivalently fast on the selection, but then there's the overhead of having it in a jQuery object so it'll be, by nature, slower than the default selector. Just depends on what you're trying to accomplish, natch.

Comment: If passing *only* an ID selector to the `jQuery()` function, it strips the `#` and passes the resulting ID to `document.getElementById()`. Only for that case, though.

Comment: @BoltClock ~ Yeah I think I should have left that part out, because by ID is supposedly going to be a 1 object return and really fast, but I wanted to illustrate the idea that using the jQuery selector as a regular practice isn't going to be a terrible thing. (yes yes, I know, all things in moderation and there's overhead and blah blah blah ;) )

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery selector `$('#myElement')` returns a jQuery object.

However, you *can* get the DOM element out of the jQuery object by doing `$('#myElement')[0]`.

So, you can do `$(object2).val('fill in with this text')` or `$(object2)[0].value = 'fill in with this text'`

Answer (score -1):

`$('idelement').val()` will return the element's value
as well as `document.getElementById('idelement').value`.
This is  my first post on this platform I am trying to format it 
much as possible.

This is the output from my chrome devtool `$('idelement')` and
`document.getElementById('idelement')` are very much different as they 
output different data structure to retrieved values using jquery it is much to use `$('idelement').val()` not `$('idelement').value` in case u are using javascript use 
`document.getElementById('idelement').value` not `document.getElementById('idelement').val()`

**Hope this will help u guys**

```
document.getElementById('compond_amount_txt')
<input type=​"text" class=​"form-control" name=​"compond_amount_txt" id=​
"compond_amount_txt" value=​"10000" aria-describedby=​"basic-addon2">​

$('#compond_amount_txt')
w.fn.init [input#compond_amount_txt.form-control]0: 
input#compond_amount_txt.form-controllength: 1__proto__: Object(0)

$('#compond_amount_txt').value
undefined

$('#compond_amount_txt').val()
"10000"

document.getElementById('compond_amount_txt').val()
VM4296:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).val is not a 
function
at <anonymous>:1:47
(anonymous) @ VM4296:1

document.getElementById('compond_amount_txt').value
"10000"
```